# CSS3 accordion menu 3 levels

Tags: html, css, menu, nav

Is there a way to extend this designmodo example to allow for 3 levels of navigation?
I’d very much like to use this menu example, but I can’t figure out how to add a third level of functionality. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Example:
http://designmodo.com/css3-accordion-menu/

Here is a fiddle that i'm working with: http://jsfiddle.net/johnstonian/r5rEZ/

Here is a sample menu i'm working with:

```
<ul class="accordion">

        <li id="one" class="files">
          <a href="#one">My Files<span>495</span></a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="five">
                <a href="#one"><em>01</em>Dropbox<span>42</span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a><em>01</em>3rd Level<span>9</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#five"><em>02</em>3rd Level<span>14</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#five"><em>03</em>3rd Level<span>3</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#one"><em>02</em>Skydrive<span>87</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#one"><em>03</em>FTP Server<span>366</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#one"><em>01</em>Dropbox<span>42</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li id="two" class="mail">
          <a href="#two">Mail<span>26</span></a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#two"><em>01</em>Hotmail<span>9</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#two"><em>02</em>Yahoo<span>14</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#two"><em>03</em>Gmail<span>3</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li id="three" class="cloud">
          <a href="#three">Cloud<span>58</span></a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#three"><em>01</em>Connect<span>12</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#three"><em>02</em>Profiles<span>19</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#three"><em>03</em>Options<span>27</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li id="four" class="sign">
          <a href="#four">Sign Out</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#four"><em>01</em>Log Out</a></li>
            <li><a href="#four"><em>02</em>Delete Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#four"><em>03</em>Freeze Account</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
```

Comment: What problems are you having ?

Comment: You don't have any 3rd-level menus in your HTML...

Comment: i'm having a problem showing the 3rd level ul/li elements. trying to figure out how to modify the css to allow for 3rd level targeting using the pseudo :target method. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnstonian/r5rEZ/

What i'd like to happen is show a list of items below 'Dropbox' when  clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a menu designed for this, such as:

- [CSSPlay: Multi-Level Flyout Menu](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/ul-flyout.html)
- [CSSPlay: A cross-browser drop-down cascading validating menu](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/dd_valid.html)
- [CSSPlay: The ULTIMATE CSS only drop-down menu](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_drop.html)